# Same login on multiple different Laravel projects

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, session

I have many projects as **subdomains** for **maindomain**:
**(haderegypt.com, doctors.haderegypt.com, treats.haderegypt.com)**
i need to share login between them like for instance if i logged on **examble.com** so i logged on **site1.examble.com** as well and vice versa

i tried already **many method** that they published on **stackoverflow, laracasts** but unfortunately not work for me, i tried this method with all his details:
[pic-method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlB0T.png)

for now i test the method between **(haderegypt.com, doctors.haderegypt.com)**
but i dont know really what the messing part that made it failed
all project has already get and send data from same database (**ecom1_hader**) on table (**users**)
and also both of them use same name of **cookie** and **session** and the same **app_name** and also use same **APP_KEY**
but after i did all this steps and make **config:clear, config:cache** i found **login** on each of them work well but once i open just the another domain both of them make **logout** for examble now i **logged** on **examble.com** once i open **site1.examble.com** the **examble.com** make **logout** by force i dont know why

and these are the content of Files (**ENV, session.php, auth.php**) of each project

project **haderegypt.com** (auth.php):

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Confirmation Timeout
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
| times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
| confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
|
*/

'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

project **haderegypt.com** (session.php):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 12000),

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
| list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
| must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
|
| Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
|
*/

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

// 'cookie' => env(
//     'SESSION_COOKIE',
//     Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'HaderEgypt'), '_').'_session'
// ),
'cookie' => 'HaderEgypt_cookie',
// 'cookie' => env('SESSION_COOKIE', 'session_sharing_application_session'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
// 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'haderegypt.com'),
// 'domain' => '.haderegypt.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Same-Site Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
| take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
| will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
|
| Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
|
*/

// 'same_site' => 'https://haderegypt.com',
'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

project **haderegypt.com** (ENV):

```
APP_NAME=HaderEgypt
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:z00Bai5cRhY++I3h4ad4w8REeU1YhOlSzXWo93P2UO8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ecom1_hader
DB_USERNAME=<redacted>
DB_PASSWORD=<redacted>

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=30000

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.haderegypt.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<redacted>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<redacted>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@haderegypt.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

---

project **doctors.haderegypt.com** (auth.php):

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Confirmation Timeout
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
| times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
| confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
|
*/

'password_timeout' => 10800,

];

Blockquote
```

project **doctors.haderegypt.com** (session.php):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 12000),

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
| list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
| must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
|
| Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
|
*/

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

// 'cookie' => env(
//     'SESSION_COOKIE',
//     Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'HaderEgypt'), '_').'_session'
// ),
'cookie' => 'HaderEgypt_cookie',
// 'cookie' => env('SESSION_COOKIE', 'session_sharing_application_session'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

// 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
// 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'haderegypt.com'),
'domain' => '.haderegypt.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Same-Site Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
| take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
| will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
|
| Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
|
*/

// 'same_site' => 'https://haderegypt.com',
'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

project **doctors.haderegypt.com** (ENV):

```
APP_NAME=HaderEgypt
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:z00Bai5cRhY++I3h4ad4w8REeU1YhOlSzXWo93P2UO8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ecom1_hader_clinics
DB_USERNAME=<redacted>
DB_PASSWORD=<redacted>

DB_CONNECTION_2=mysql
DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=ecom1_hader
DB_USERNAME_2=<redacted>
DB_PASSWORD_2=<redacted>

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=30000

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.haderegypt.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<redacted>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<redacted>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@haderegypt.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

can anyone check what the wrong in my script please

Comment: Your database and mail credentials are in your post, I recommend you change them **as soon as possible**.

Comment: Is your database configuration same for the main and sub-domain?

Comment: And yes, which method do you want to go with? Session or Database?

Comment: D1    1 yes sir its already the same database and table and  can try to login with the same email:password on both of them to sure and also the same email and details of smtp

Comment: Mitesh Rathod , i already connected the database between them that part succeed already with no problem but the second part in i want to share the login whether with session or cookie or some method else i dont mind but we can take the easly method to try or u can suggest ur opinion